# Generic type unknown

Tags: typescript

Given the following code, how to force `MODEL_ENDPOINT` be a `Endpoint<StringModel, String>` and not `Endpoint<StringModel, unknown>`?

```js
export abstract class Model<T> {
    abstract parse(): T;
}
export class Endpoint<T extends Model<V>, V> {
    constructor(public MCreator: new() => T) {
    }

    parse(): T {
        const d = new this.MCreator();
        return d;
    }
}
class StringModel extends Model<string> {
    parse(): string {
        return "abc";
    }

}
export const MODEL_ENDPOINT = new Endpoint(StringModel);
```

Comment: Why not make `Endpoint` generic over a single type argument `T`, then use `Model<T>`? https://tsplay.dev/wenPBN

Comment: I have some problem doing like that on ```parse()``` method of the ```Model```. I will try again...